# Jqgrid dynamic combo box population not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid, response

I am trying to dynamically populate an inline combobox in the JQqgrid. The ajax request is sent to the "dataUrl" parameter however I am unable to set the response successfully to the combobox. Neither the buildSelect function or the other functions I have tried were called upon the return of the response from the server. I have posted my code below, can anyone point out why the buildSelect doesn't get called and I am unable to set the dynamic data to the drop down list. Note that I have also browsed stackoverflow for similar questions but with no success.

```
            { name: 'hotelId', index:'hotelId',width:30, editable: true, edittype:'select',
              editoptions: { dataUrl:'itemPricingNew!loadRevenueCodes.action' + '?hotelId='+$("#hotelId").val(),
                            value : function (data ){
                                //var response = toObject(data.responseText).response;
                                //return  response.reqRevenueCode;
                                alert("Test22");
                            },
                                buildSelect: function(data) {
                                    alert("Test");
                                },
                                dataInit : function (elem){
                                    alert("Test11");
                                } 
                            }
            },
            /*{ name: 'hotelId', index:'hotelId',width:30, editable: true, edittype:'select',
              editoptions: { value: { 176: 'One', 177: 'Two'} }
            },*/
```

MilindaD

Answer (score 1):

hi :) you can dynamically do it with Append to the combobox options with the Jquery and then add it to the jqgrid

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/dynamic-combobox-listbox-dropdown-in-javascript.html

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a javascript method which makes an ajax call and fetches the list of all the items you need in the combo box.

```
var httpDropdown = new XMLHttpRequest();

var finalString;
```

Store the string in a global variable and use that string as edit options.

```
function getDropdown() {

    var actionURL = "itemPricingNew!loadRevenueCodes.action";

    httpDropdown.open("POST", actionURL, true);
    httpDropdown.onreadystatechange = parseDropdown;
    httpDropdown.send(null);
} 

function parseDropdown() {

    if (httpDropdown.readyState == 4) {

         var rootElement = httpDropdown.responseXML.documentElement;

         var allChildren = rootElement.childNodes;
         var key;
         var value;

         for(var i=0; i<allChildren.length-1; i++) {

            key = allChildren[i].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            value = allChildren[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            finalString += key+":"+value+";";
            createGrid();
         }
    }
}
```

First do all the processing and then call the createGrid method

```
function createGrid() {

     jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({editoptions: {value: finalString}});
}
```

Comment: Hi while that is a partial solution. How would it possible to lets say load data dynamically when the row is edited or when there is another combo box that needs to be populated upon the selection of the current combo box list.